# Float H2 - Need to push text below

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I need to push the text next to the H2 below it. Not sure why I cant work this out but any help would be great.

Note: You are looking at the left side.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/3kzGg/3/)

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="item">
            <h2>Item 1</h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </span>
            <div class="button">Button</div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {
    height: 60px;
    width: 98%;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.item span {
    font-size: 10px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}

.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 98%;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    background: gray;
    float: right;
}
```

I have tried to float the text, change the display even just margin it down but I would like a good way to do this. Any help would be great, cheers all!

Comment: This is very Basic of HTML !!!

Comment: @Deekey Wait a second. Your going to downvote this because I ran into a problem and just couldn't think at the time how to solve it? Is that not why this site exists?

Comment: Opps...I came out of this.....not interested in arguements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I would like to point out that your DOM is not structured correctly, consider using sub wrappers, `float` one to the `left` and other to the `right`.

The reason you are coming across that issue is, `h2` is floated, `span` is `inline` so it will sit right besides your `h2`. Assigning `display: block;` will result your `right` block to be pushed down, if `width` is not assigned. Better consider changing the DOM, I've shared my solution below.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WbyM9/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="box clear">
    <div>
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
        <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    width: 550px;
}

.box > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}

.box > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: @NathanLee Heya, thank you, was just working on the widths, I just missed that, would like to point out that if the content increases,  your solution will fail, would like to upvote if you fix that :D http://jsfiddle.net/3kzGg/9/

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you for the answer and the effort put into this. I will be using this now as it is a lot better then mine. Im always looking for ways to improve and this has helped a lot. +1 and correct! Thanks again.

Comment: @Ruddy No problem, happy cssing :)

Comment: @NathanLee great, just forgot the `width` on `span` but never mind you fixed so will give you a + :) but markup was the only thing which troubled him :)

Comment: Exactly @Mr.Alien, but it is good that he is refining his solution to yours which will give a lot of semantic meaning to his code. Cheers.

Comment: I really like this better-practice solution.  For reference, I posted a solution based on the current HTML if for some reason the HTML could not be changed. @Ruddy

Comment: @MarcAudet Ah thanks, its not a problem for me to change the HTML but its always good to see how it could be done otherwise. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3kzGg/8/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
span{
     display:block;
     clear:both;
     margin-bottom: -40px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh thats my bad as I forgot to say, this pushes the "button" down. I need that to stay in the div `item`. Thanks for your fast answer tho.

Comment: No worries, just add a `margin-bottom: -40px;` to my above class and that will be proper. - @Ruddy

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="left">
        <h2>Item 1</h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button">Button</div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    float:left;
}
```

I have used `.left` to left-align heading and text and cleared floats on `.item`.
And removed `float:left` from `h2`

Hope it helps you.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3kzGg/14/)

Comment: Cool and crisp solution. But you could also add `.clr` to your previous div to get the same effect instead of adding the mark up. Anyways, +1 frm me :)

Comment: Very nice, thanks for the answer. I like this but I think I will go with Mr. Alien as it looks a lot cleaner then my code. Thanks tho! +1

Comment: @Ruddy - I think your choice is correct, as Mr. Alien has also elaborated ways to clean up your unstructured mark up to a good extent. Thumbs up

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Yes. that messiness is because of Ruddy's unstructured code. But yes, even in the same scenario, I think http://jsfiddle.net/3kzGg/11/ this one works.

Comment: @NathanLee text is overlapping on the button in this fiddle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39822/discussion-between-nathan-lee-and-hiral)

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you can't change the HTML mark-up, you can try the following CSS:

```
.item {
    height: 60px;
    width: 98%;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.item span {
    font-size: 10px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}

.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Since `.item` has a fixed height, you can also fix the height of `.button`, say 50px.

You can now use absolute position to place the button to the right (give a 5px offset to top and right).

For the `span`, you can `float: left` and use `clear: both` to force it to start a new line after the `h1`.

However, I would also add a right-margin of 60px to make sure that longer test does not conflict with the button.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/tNd2s/

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes more sense to unfloat everything and position the button absolutely.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/hQyEf/)

```
.item {
    height: 60px;
    width: 98%;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    position:relative;
}

.item span {
    font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
}

.button {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:1%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    background: gray;
}
```